# pinterest widget main.js file not loading

Tags: pinterest

I want to add a pinterest widget to my site.  I've customized it and added the code: 
`<a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://www.pinterest.com/bigrockpremiuml/"></a>
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>`

When I then test it in my browser, it cannot find a js file referenced in that script which is this

```
http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js
```

The error I get in the console is because it cannot find the file.

```
file://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js
```

So the browser is looking for the file in my local storage instead of the link....help

Comment: Are you testing locally without a server running? If you serve your content with a server the browser should recognize the //assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js link.

Comment: when I run with a server, I get a different error.  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE @ZackArgyle

Comment: I was able to work by running the server like you suggested.  Thanks! @ZackArgyle